# 404 on RESTful service created with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, api, rest, tomcat, amazon-ec2

I just deployed a RESTFul Spring Boot/maven service to Tomcat 10.1.9 running on a Amazon EC2 Linux instance, but it returns a 404.

[image: Not Found error]
It does however work when I launch it from Eclipse and connect via Postman.

Is it possible that I'm missing some sort of servlet mapping in the pom.xml (there is no web.xml)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.11</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>ca.allauto</groupId>
    <artifactId>ups</artifactId>
    <version>v1</version>
    <name>ups</name>
    <description>RESTful service for UPS application</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
   etc...
```

The name of the war file is "ups-v1" so I am using the URL:

http://[Public EC2 IPv4 address]:8080/ups-v1/api/ups

In the controller, I created a RequestMapping of "/api/ups":

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UpsController {
    @Autowired
    UpsService upsService;
    
    @GetMapping(value="/ups")
    public List<Ups> readUps() {
        return upsService.getUps();
    }
    // etc...
```

Should I add a web.xml file?